# Liferay Message Board "User Profile Picture" hide option?

Tags: liferay

I want to hide the avatars in message board thread but I am not getting any such option in the interface of configuration. Can anyone suggest me how can I proceed further?

Comment: As per my understanding I got an idea how to edit User profile Picture in Message Board. Inside message_board portlet file "view_thread_message.jspf" is having following code:                             <liferay-ui:user-display
 userId="<%= message.getUserId() %>"
 userName="<%= message.getUserName() %>"
 displayStyle="<%= 2 %>"
>                                                                      But not sure which part I have to remove for user profile picture removal. Any guidance will be great for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily remove the user profile picture from the message board, but if you remove this, then that will be deleted from entire liferay portal.

Please have a look at

> /portal-web/docroot/html/taglib/ui/user_display/start.jsp.

Here find the `class="avatar"`, this line is actually display image of the user profile picture.

So, here we have 2 approaches.

1) Remove the `<img>` tag from the an above jsp.

2) If you want to remove from message board only, then write simple jquery which will hide the `<img>` tag with `class="avatar"`.